# how to change r,g,b color to 2 coordinates in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, coordinates, rgb, dimensions

```
from PIL import Image

picture = Image.open("C:/Lab/photos/frog2.png")
r,g,b = picture.getpixel( (0,0) )
print("Red: {0}, Green: {1}, Blue: {2}".format(r,g,b))
```

the result is Red: 57, Green: 66, Blue: 19
but i want to change this r,g,b to 2 coorinates like(x,y)

what should i type?

Comment: Can you give an example output of that "two coordinates" when the input is `r=57, g=66, b=19`?

Comment: What space are you trying to transform those colours into?

Comment: sorry for the confusing. i am not being able to make some codes for "two coordinates".I mean that i can only make r,g,b color from the image but i want to make 2coordinates(screen-space? or x,y) by using r:57, g=66, b=19. that is it

Comment: That hasn't really answered my question; yours is unanswerable until you've figured out how **you want** to transform from 3D to 2D coordinates.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Could be [CIE 1931](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space).

Answer (score 3):

[`colormath`](https://github.com/gtaylor/python-colormath) can be used to convert a RGB color to a xyY color, and from there you can simply ignore the Y coordinate in order to get a xy chromacity.